# A question about linear operator on a finite dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $(V,\langle·,·\rangle)$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space. Suppose $T\in \mathscr{L}( V )$ and all the eigenvalues $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ of $T$ has $|\lambda| < 1$. Prove that for any given $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such
that
$$||T^{n} v|| \leq \epsilon||v||$$for every $v \in V$.

Comment: Have you tried considering the Jordan Normal Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case $1$: $v$ is in the eigenspace.

Let $B=\{v_1 ... v_m \}$ be a basis for the eigenspace of $V$ consisting of linearly independent eigenvectors.  If $v \in span(B)$ we're easily done as $v = \sum \alpha_i v_i$ and so $T(v) =  \sum \alpha_i T(v_i) = \sum \alpha_i \lambda_iv_i$  And for n sufficiently large $$||T^n(v)|| =  || \sum \alpha_i \lambda_i ^n v_i|| \leq  \sum_{i = 1} ^m |\alpha_i| \ |\lambda_i ^n|  \ ||v_i||  \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$  since $|\lambda _i| ^n \to 0$ by the fact that $|\lambda _i| < 1$

Case $2$: Now extend $B$ to be a basis for all of $V$, namely $\{v_1 ... v_m, w_1 ...w_n\}$.  Now, if there exists $k$ such that $T^k(w_i) \in span\{ v_1, v_2,...v_m\}$ then $T^k(w_i) = \sum \alpha _i v_i$ and we have $$||T^{k+l}(w_i)|| \leq \sum \alpha_i |\lambda_i |^l  ||v_i|| \to 0$$

as $l \to \infty$

Thus we need only to look at when $T(w_i) \in span( w_1, ... w_n)$ See if you can do that

Comment: It does appear you need the Jordan Normal Form for this.